# Web API 2 Token Expiring / Denied

Tags: angularjs, token, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using web api 2 token based authentication, local storage, with an Angular app I wrote.  Thanks to the article by Taiseer Joudeh.  Everything is working great except that after an hour or so users are being denied access by web api [Authorize] with the same token that worked when first logging in.  The token is still present in local storage.  I'm using the default 14 day timeout.  Where might the token be getting timed out / expired?  Here is the ConfigureAuth function I'm using:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }
    public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };

        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe its do to with those Cookies you're allowing. What time out do they have?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check on the cookies in firebug.  I don't think I need or use cookies since I'm using local storage to store username and token data.  Should I just comment out the two cookie enable lines in the code above?

Comment: The solution to the problem was increasing the Idle Timeout value in IIS for the application pool / worker process which had defaulted to 20 minutes.

Comment: @AustinHarris - have you figured out a way to remove the user token on the client side ? i.e. if user clicks on a `Logout` button, what is the best way to delete that auth token.